# JSch read local log file

Tags: jsch

I am developing a tool that use JSch library to read log files from remote machine for log parsing and some other functionality.  The code to read the log file is given below.

```
    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect();

    ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    sftp.connect();

    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        //this will be changed to execute on a regular time interval
        while (true) {
            stream = sftp.get(rfile);
            read(stream);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
        sftp.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

But, there is a chance that the tool will be deployed to the machine where the log is generated.  So, my question is,

1)  I suspect a performance issue using the *sftp.get()* as the log file will be read in a regular interval(eg. 5 mins).  Any suggestion to improve performance here ?

2)  whether JSch will have the same network overhead for reading files from the local machine similar to the remote machine.

3)  If yes, is there any way to improve the performance if the log is reading from a local machine.

May be i can check the ip address of both the target and host machine before reading the log file.  And if both are same i can read the log directly.  But, could there be any better alternative?

Thanks,
nks